# What methods to use for PHP Field Validation

Tags: php, mysql, regex, validation, post

What are *<del>the best practices</del> other* methods; outside of

```
!empty();
isset();
!is_null();
```

and assigning a value to a variable e.g.

```
$variable = $_POST['value']`
```

Do I use to make sure form data is validated to be clean enough to use?

Do I go to the lengths of trying to use field length and regex validations?

If the endpoint is an API using MySQL and PHP, does using `htmlspecialchars()` cause potential issues with loss of data using these methods?

Comment: It depends on what you need to validate... For example to check if an email is valid don't use `!empty();`

Comment: You're mixing a few things, validation / sanitation, SQL injections / XSS., and so on. Overall, this question is way too broad for SO imho, and there're plenty of resources out there for each topic.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` shouldn't be used when saving data, only on output, so you shouldn't have any loss of data.

Comment: But would I use it just to make sure that the $_POST['email'] actually has something in it, and then check it's an email using regex or something, or just skip straight to the regex?

Comment: Try this
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp

Comment: Make sure you bind all variables, this prevents things like injection. validating at the form and using !empty are perfectly fine validation techniques

Comment: Can I ask why `regex` is an included tag? What does this have to do with RegEx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter_input method and use a filter like `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`. Its the better way to filter your post paramters. [function.filter-input.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Answer (score 1):

For input validation, I would point you to the Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP). The have pages on [data validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation), [PHP filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters), [cheat sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet), and [XSS protection](http://php%20sanitize%20input%20owasp).

Since you specifically referenced MySQL, I would note that the best security practice is to use PDO or MySQLi to parameterize your statements. Parameterized statements are much more effective than relying on sanitized input in preventing MySQL injection as PHP does not rely on syntax to differentiate user input and the SQL query itself. When accessing data from the database, however, `htmlspecialchars()` can still come in handy to prevent XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answers thank you!

For the MySQL side of things parameterized statements was definitely going to be the only method used.

I guess really the most important thing for me is the submit values via the post method.

If I'm expecting JSON and only JSON then something like this should work on the server side.

```
function isJSON(MyTestStr){
    try {
        var MyJSON = JSON.stringify(MyTestStr);
        var json = JSON.parse(MyJSON);
        if(typeof(MyTestStr) == 'string')
            if(MyTestStr.length == 0)
                return false;
    }
   catch(e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then I should be able to do anything further by pulling out the values from the JSON directly and use them in the PHP script without much fear.

Answer (score 0):

Each use of input data needs different filtering / protection.

First, I like to do

```
$foo = @$_POST['foo'];
if (empty(foo)) ... // take different action if foo is totally missing (not just blank)
```

For inserting into MySQL, use the escaping mechanism available in the API -- `real_escape_string`, or "binding".  Do not use the `mysql_*` API, it has been replaced by `mysqli_*`.  Do not combine multiple queries into a single call.

For displaying on an HTML page, use `htmlentities`.  Note:  Do not use that before inserting into a database table; that just clutters the table.  Instead, have the discipline to use it just before displaying.

If you have an old version of PHP, you might be tempted to use Magic Quotes.  Don't!  As a comment puts it "[This] one-size-fits-all approach to escaping/quoting is wrongheaded and downright dangerous."

For JSON, I like  `json_encode(...)` and `json_decode(..., TRUE)`.